# Specifying version of python to be used to run a script

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have both python 2.7 and 3.2 installed on my system. I want some scripts to run using python 3.2, and some using 2.7 However, I don't want to go to IDLE every time to run scripts. Can anything be done such that the scripts execute themselves in the version specified?

I have tried some experimentation with sys and os modules, but that turned out to be useless.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 6):

**If you are on *nix system then you can use [Shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)**

Example :

- `#!/usr/bin/env python3.2`

Or

- `#!/usr/bin/env python2.7`

Or You can run script using specific version

Example:

- `python2.7  yourscript.py`

**If you are on Windows System then you can use**

- `#!/Python26/python`

Comment: To complete the answer if OP is running windows, you can do `#!/Python26/python` to run Python2.6 for instance.

Comment: IIRC, the Windows python runner tool (py.exe) can read the Unix shebangs just fine.